# What is so special about the Ultima Thule passed by New Horizon spacecraft?

Tags: asteroids

I read that the New Horizon spacecraft passed by the Ultima Thule. I also got to know that it is a flat, snowman-shaped rock.

What is so special about it?

Comment: What's your prior research? Did you read the wikipedia page on Ultima Thule / New Horizons?

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult to find the Wikipedia page for [Ultima Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(486958)_2014_MU69).

Comment: I am not doing any research.

Comment: I am just curious about space so I asked

Comment: Hello, Please take the [tour]. By research we mean that you can ask a better question if you try find out about it first. You *should* read the wikipedia page first. It will make your question better. You have done research already because you know "that it is flat".  Learning that is "research".

Answer (score 2):

- Ultima Thule is the first small Kuiper Belt Object (KBO) we have visited. For the first time, we can see a KBO as more than a tiny point of light in a telescope.
- it seems to be flat, rather than roughly round. This is really unusual (we've never seen that shape before in planets, moons, asteroids etc.).